# Apply PMML predictor model in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, knime, pmml

Knime has generated for me a [PMML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language) model. At this time I want to apply this model to a python process. What is the right way to do this?

More in depth: I develop a [django student attendance system](https://code.google.com/p/ghap/). The application is already so mature that I have time to implement the 'I'm feeling lucky' button to automatically fill an attendance form. Here is where PMML comes in. Knime has generated a PMML model that predicts student attendance. Also, thanks to django for being so productive that I time for this great work ;)

[image]

Comment: What is exactly the problem? You can export the PMML model from KNIME with PMML Writer. One of the PMML processing libs in Python is [Augustus](https://code.google.com/p/augustus/) ([help to use it](http://174.129.21.118/augustus/Primer/html/basic-walkthrough-gaslog-consumer.html#run-augustus-as-a-model-consumer)). (I have no experience with Augustus.)

Comment: @GáborBakos, I have not experience with Augustus. I will like to call a simple prediction function: `prediction = please_predict( model.xml, dict )` . I this that I will code my self a function to do it, it is not complex for a decision tree.

Comment: It seems it (Augustus) can perform easy prediction, although you have to make a few transformations (convert to xml, convert back from xml). You can hide this to such a detail behind the function you provided.

Comment: @GáborBakos, I'm waiting for someone with Augustus expertice to know best steps to deploy it.

Comment: ok, have you check the documentation I linked? It does not seem to be too complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have wrote my own code. Be free to contribute or fork it:

https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/lightpmmlpredictor

Answer (score 2):

The code for Augustus, to score PMML models in Python, is at https://code.google.com/p/augustus/

Comment: Does Augustus support Association Model? Because I am getting AssociationModel has not been implemented yet error.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [PyPMML](https://github.com/autodeployai/pypmml) to apply PMML in Python, for example:

```
from pypmml import Model

model = Model.fromFile('the/pmml/file/path')
result = model.predict(data)
```

The data could be dict, json, Series or DataFrame of Pandas.

If you use PMML in PySpark, you could use [PyPMML-Spark](https://github.com/autodeployai/pypmml-spark), for example:

```
from pypmml_spark import ScoreModel

model = ScoreModel.fromFile('the/pmml/file/path')
score_df = model.transform(df)
```

The df is a DataFrame of PySpark.

For more info about other PMML libraries, be free to see:
https://github.com/autodeployai